# Header doesn't work with background img

Tags: html, css, image, web, background

I'm about to redesign my site. In the `Body` css I've put the background-img. Then I've made a `div class="header"` for the header, of course.

But when I publish the page the header don't show up. I've tried on several browsers and computers but nothing to see. 
Then I tried on my phone. On the phone It works only in portrait-mode, but not in landscape like on a desktop. On the iPad's the same.

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <title>Home</title>

            <style type="text/css">
                * {padding: 0; margin: 0;}
                body {background: url(http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3785/9603354598_e7a32b5505_o.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover;  -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover; }
                .header {margin-top: 50px; width: 1400px; position:fixed; height: 70px; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /* Fallback for web browsers that doesn't support RGBa */ background: rgb(0, 0, 0) transparent;  /* RGBa with 0.6 opacity */  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);  /* For IE 5.5 - 7*/ filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000); /* For IE 8*/ -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000)"; color: white; margin-top: 80%; }
                .titles {opacity: 1;  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;  font-weight: 300;}
                .title {margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 2%; font-size: 40px; font-family: Futura, "Trebuchet MS", Arial, sans-serif;}
                .subtitle {margin-top: -12px; margin-left: 130px; font-size: 10px; font-family: Futura, "Trebuchet MS", Arial, sans-serif;}
            </style>

  </head>

        <body>
     <div class="header">
        <div class="titles" align="left">
          <div class="title">TITLE</div>
          <div class="subtitle">subtitle</div>
        </div>
     </div>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Any idea where the problem is ?
In my code application,the page work perfectly.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove your margin top in your header css. I commented this in example below. Please ignore my red border, just used it as "debug".

Check my [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/franchez/hzJq2/2/)

```
.header {
    margin-top: 50px; 
    width: 1400px; 
    position:fixed; 
    height: 70px; 
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
    /* Fallback for web browsers that doesn't support RGBa */ 
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0) transparent;  
    /* RGBa with 0.6 opacity */  
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);  
    /* For IE 5.5 - 7*/ 
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000); 
    /* For IE 8*/
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000)"; 
    color: white;
/* margin-top: 80%;*/ 
}
```